# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The multi-part identifier "EMPREG.EMPACCOUNTNO" could not be bound

Tags: database, select, join, sql-server-2012, inner-join

After executing this query:

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(GRP.EMPCODE,GRP.EMPGROUPID) GROUP_ID,
GRPMEM.EMPGROUPMEMBERNO MEMBER_ID
FROM DBO.EMPREGISTER AS EMPREG , DBO.EMPGROUP AS GRP
INNER JOIN DBO.EMPGROUPMEMBER AS GRPMEM  ON GRPMEM.CGMGROUPID = GRP.EMPGROUPID
INNER JOIN DBO.EMPACCOUNT AS EMPACC  ON EMPACC.EMPACCOUNTNO = EMPREG.EMPACCOUNTNO
```

I got exception :

**Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The multi-part identifier "EMPREG.EMPACCOUNTNO" could not be bound.**

please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, on table DBO.EMPREGISTER there isn't the column EMPACCOUNTNO.
are you sure, where this column is?
i think this column is on table DBO.EMPGROUP - GRP
maybe if you post the structure, i can help you more.